# why am i still unable to push my code to github?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm somewhat of a `git` newbie and the following has happened:
I've been working on a project, created a branch & happily committed and pushed code to github, no pronlem, then at some point, I've changed my github name, i.e. I updated my remote with `git remote set-url origin NEWURL` I confirmed with `remote -v` but `git push` still failed. I attempted to `git rebase config_options/config_options` after which it said `│fatal: Needed a single revision` and I still can't `git push`, what else do Ineed to do??

```
$ git push To https://github.com/stdcerr/scaper.git ! 
[rejected]                 master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/stdcerr/scaper.git' 
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote 
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes 
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have tried to do a `git pull` too, but I only get `Already up-to-date.`
I tried `git pull --rebase` and got the following:

```
$ git pull --rebase
Current branch config_options is up to date.
ron@regDesktopHome:~/src/scaper$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 353 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/stdcerr/scaper.git
   3747bbb..06a769e  config_options -> config_options
    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/stdcerr/scaper.git'
    hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
    hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
    hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

Comment: What is the error message when the git push "failed?"  Was it complaining about your credentials, or about the push itself?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the message above!

Comment: You can overwrite the remote repository with `git push -f` but other peaple using the repo will have to merge it.

Comment: You need to git push --force: I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often seen when you create a new repository with a commit in it (for initial README or LICENSE files) instead of creating an *empty* repository (with no commit and no files)

If you create an empty repository, then you can push without issue.

If not, you would need a `git pull --rebase` first, then `git push --force`.